# Sharing Python Programs with others

Tags: python, file-sharing

I am trying to share my program with others who do not have python installed or any of the libraries required to run my program. It uses Pyairmore which never comes pre-installed with anything. Does anyone have any idea on what I should do be able to send my program to others. I tried doing pythoninstaller but the computer I sent the .exe file was not able to open it.

Comment: Maybe look into freezing your code.

Comment: I tried using Pyinstaller but my friend's computer wouldn't open it for some reason. And when I tried to save it to google drive it wouldn't open because google kept flagging it as a virus

Comment: It most likely didn't open on your friend's computer because he had a different computer architecture.